# Vector data source being cached in QGIS? And is there a way to auto-reload?

Tags: qgis, cache, refresh

I'm using KoboToolBox to capture GPS location data from mobile. It is stored in a cloud table, and can be accessed via API using a URL.

Initially I captured 8 points that I can see in the cloud table. And I was able to load and display them in QGIS using `Layer`-> `Data Source Manager`-> `Vector Protocol`: https://dgcfx:KoboTestPassword@kf.kobotoolbox.org/api/v2/assets/aK6sQnBthzp7qK6kZMCJJe/data/?format=geojson  (yes, I know I just gave away my mighty test password)

All good. It loaded and displayed the 8 points. Awesome! Happy!

BUT...then I went into KoboToolBox and deleted a point. Gone! All good. EXCEPT...the point did not magically disappear from my QGIS map. OK, I only half-hoped it would. So I removed the QGIS vector layer and remade it. You'd think 7 points this time. BUT NO...still 8. So I thought maybe it's not really gone and KoboToolBox API is still serving it up. It wasn't. Proof: I put the same URL into my web browser and got 7 points.

```
{
"type": "FeatureCollection",
"name": "Test 1",
"features": [
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.097163, -35.151851, 9.496608751825988]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T10:53:57.390+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T10:54:58.596+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "weed"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.097153, -35.151839, 7.339992540888488]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T10:54:58.639+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T10:55:42.016+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "road"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.091695, -35.152953, 90.59601211547852]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T11:50:01.726+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T11:50:12.617+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "weed"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.091631, -35.15295, 90.20915603637695]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T11:50:12.660+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T11:51:09.033+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "road"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.091658, -35.155855, 61.02303695678711]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T16:06:08.300+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T16:07:03.934+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "road"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.091575, -35.155855, 42.36782457306981]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T16:07:52.401+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T16:08:01.293+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "road"}},
{"type": "Feature", "geometry": {"type": "Point", "coordinates": [174.091342, -35.153337, 88.72640611417592]}, "properties": {"start": "2023-05-10T16:08:01.314+12:00", "end": "2023-05-10T16:08:53.553+12:00", "Type_of_issue": "road"}}
]
}
```

So I reckon QGIS must be caching the URL data somewhere. But where? And why? And how do I make it stop?
And one more thing: I don't really want to have to remove and redo the layer to pull and display refreshed up-to-date data from KoboToolBox. Is there any way (preferably without code) to set up auto-refresh at some interval, say every minute?